# DynamicReport - How to plot too many data points

Tags: jfreechart, linechart, dynamic-reports

I am trying to create LineChartReport using more than 1000 data points. Problem is that the X Axis should show the time stamp, and since there are too many data points, the data gets overlapped and no comprehensible data is shown. So I need help on following 2 points:
    1. Limit the data points on X-Axis (only) to say 25. The number of data points for the graph/chart still remains at 1000
    2. Rotate the Timestamp data by 90 degrees so that the Timestamp data is recorded correctly and not truncated.

```
Have tried to get the domain axis and manipulate it, like this, but the library does not allow that:

CategoryAxis domainAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(false);
domainAxis.clearCategoryLabelToolTips();
chart.getCategoryPlot().getDataset().getColumnKeys()
CategoryDataset ds = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDataset();
List ls = ds.getColumnKeys();
List ls2 = new ArrayList();

int i = 0;
for (Iterator it = ls.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    it.next(); 
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        ls2.add(ls.get(i));
    }
    i++;
}
chart.getCategoryPlot().setDataset(ds);



Sample image with 10 data points appear here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B-m6SCJULOTRdHZ6cUwxX041SHM

Any suggestions ??
```

Answer (score 1):

The below codes are based on DynamicReport 4.0.2. I didn't test them in other versions.

Regarding your first question, you want 1000 points of data, and just want the few data in line chart. In this case, you need to use the different data source for you data table and line chart.

Firstly, create the subreport for the data table and set up.

```
SubreportBuilder subreport = cmp.subreport(
    report().setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
            .addColumn(
                col.column("Name", "name", type.stringType()), 
                col.column("Counts", "value", type.integerType())
            )
);
JasperReportBuilder reportContent = report();
subreport.setDataSource(allDatasource);
reportContent.summary(subreport, cmp.verticalGap(20));
```

Secondly, prepare another data source for line chart and set up.

```
reportContent.setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
    /* add title */
    .title(title, subtitle,
    /* add chart in the head of title */
    cmp.verticalList(LINE_CHART)
    /* set style */ 
    .setStyle(stl.style().setBottomPadding(30).setTopPadding(30)))
    /* set data source for line chart*/
    .setDataSource(dataSource);
```

About your second question, you need to create **customizer** at first.

```
public class DynamicLineCustomizer implements DRIChartCustomizer, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8493880774698206000L;

@Override
public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, ReportParameters reportParameters) {
    CategoryPlot plot = jFreeChart.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions
            .createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0));
    }
}
```

Then use this **customizer** in line chard builder.

```
LineChartBuilder lineChart = cht.lineChart()
    .customizers(new DynamicLineCustomizer())
    .setCategory(columns[0])
    .series(createSeries(columns))
    .setCategoryAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setLabel("TimeStamp"))
    .seriesColors(seriesColors);
```

The line chart and data table will be like below:

[image: line chart and data table]

Comment: Hi, the rotation thing worked. But I need to plot say data collected over a day (maybe every 5 seconds) on this. With 50 data points, the X Axis looks like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-m6SCJULOTRUzVERVJwYllTY0E With 1000s of data points it becomes a mess. I need to show only the hour values, example, 12:00, 01:00, 02:00 etc., instead of all the timestamps.

Comment: If you don't want 1000 points in your data, then just put the points you need in datasource. You need to manipulate your datasource.

Comment: Umm .. I NEED 1000s of data points. I do not need to show all of the X-Axis values. Need to show only a few of them. In the example on gdrive, it will be nice if we can limit the X-Axis items to say 10, but still have all 50 of the data points.

Comment: Then you need to separate the datasource from your line chart and data table. In other words, you need the different data source for line chart and data table.

Comment: hi @SuDu
I updated my answer, you can check it. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi Laurence, I think you still did not get the point. The expected solution is something like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-m6SCJULOTRajFhU1NGQ1lURVU. As you can see there are LOT of data points, but on the X-Axis we need to display only 24 hours. If this is what you meant the expected output is, I need to revisit my solution. Also, can you let me know how to decrease the font of the data on the X Axis or allow more space so that complete text appear instead of the dots (..)

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me (hope it helps somebody) :

Ref: http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1046

```
private void build(String startDate, String endDate) {
    TextColumnBuilder<Integer> i = col.column("I", "I", type.integerType());
    TextColumnBuilder<Integer> b = col.column("B", "B", type.integerType());
    TextColumnBuilder<Integer> t = col.column("T", "T", type.integerType());
    TextColumnBuilder<Date> timeColumn = col.column("TimeStamp", "TimeStamp", type.dateType());

    createDataSource(startDate, endDate);

    try {   
        TimeSeriesChartBuilder timeSeriesChartBuilder1 = cht.timeSeriesChart();
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.series(cht.serie(b), cht.serie(t), cht.serie(i));
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.setShowShapes(false);
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.setDataSource(dataSource);
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.setTimePeriod(timeColumn);
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.setTimePeriodType(TimePeriod.SECOND);
        timeSeriesChartBuilder1.setTitle("ABC Information");

        JasperReportBuilder builder = report()
                .summary(cht.multiAxisChart(timeSeriesChartBuilder1))
                .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
                .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("ABC Complete Info"))
                ;    
        builder.show();   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```